# single node tree explanation

Tags: cart

1. solution: you have a single node tree and you have this explanation. "Because of the inability to split the dataset on any variable, the average of the entire data set is applied as the estimate for all predictions."

For a single node tree, I know that you cannot make a split. You have a training set. let's say you have 6 observations. Then, from the quote, do you take average of the 6 observations and average all the predictions? can you please tell me if this is what the solution is saying?

2. If you have multiple terminal nodes, then you can make a split. Then, can you please advise me how the solution may say ?

Comment: The prediction *is* the average of the six observations if your objective is to minimize mean squared error.  Whenever you end up at a leaf (terminal) node, the prediction will just be the average of the observations in the node.

Comment: Thanks! But, shouldn't you say the prediction _comes_ from the average of the six observations instead of "is"?

Comment: *Comes from* implies there might be some transformation of the average, but this isn't the case; the value we use for prediction is equal to the average.

Comment: sorry. I am having some trouble understanding. We are doing predictive analytic. We get the raw data and we use it to predict. If we are just averaging the 6 observations, for example, then, are we really predicting anything? thanks

Comment: Yes, why would you think we weren't?  We are predicting the next value using the sample mean of previous values as the predictor.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. Now, I see where you are going. Basically, we are just averaging (i.e. looking at the past observations) to predict the next value. 

Let's say if you have many terminal nodes, then the solution would say each prediction of the terminal node as "average predictions of the observations in the node." CAn you please verify this part as well? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's correct!  Note that with different loss functions, we might use a different function of the data, e.g., with mean absolute error loss, we'd use the sample median of the observations.  We use the sample mean when trying to minimize mean squared error.

Comment: Do you know how to better word this? If you have 6 terminal nodes, the average of the observations in each node is applied as the estimate for ______. Should you say all the prediction?

Comment: How about - If you have six terminal nodes, the average of the observations in each node is used as the predicted value for unseen observations that fall into the node.

Comment: thank you. I had a question with how to sound better.  I am going to memorize your wording.

Comment: quick question. You want the SSE term to be small. SSE is just aggregation of e^2. Can you please tell me if "e" is the difference between the prediction and the average of the target observation in one node? I think it is based on what I've learned from you.

Comment: $e_i$ is the difference between the $i^{th}$ observation in the node and the average of all the observations in the node.

Answer (score 1):

A single node regression tree is sort of like a regression with only the intercept. The best you can do is predict that every observation will have the mean of the DV.

When you have more than one node, you can assign the mean for the observations in that node to every observation in that node.

(I'm saying "mean" because your question implies that that is the metric you are using).

You mention a tree with 6 observations. Maybe you were just using that as an example, but trees don't work well with so few observations.

Answer (score 0):

> can you please tell me if this is what the solution is saying?

Yes, in the case of a single node decision tree regressor, the prediction will always be the chosen metric (in this case the average) applied to the set of the target values in the observations used to build the tree, regardless of what the input is.

> If you have multiple terminal nodes, then you can make a split. Then, can you please advise me how the solution may say ?

The split is usually done at the training phase. When you have already built a decision tree using a number of labeled observations, you go from one (parent) node to another (child) node by performing a test that was associated with the parent node at training time. In the case of a binary test (e.g. $X < \mu$), the parent node will have two child nodes, each corresponding to one of the two results of the test. When you have multiple terminal nodes, you would go through the process of "passing" your input from one node to the other using the previously mentioned strategy. Doing this, your input will eventually end up at one of the terminal nodes, and then, just like in the case of a single node decision tree, your prediction will be the mean of the target values of the observations associated with that node. This mean is also computed at the training phase, just like the tests associated with each node.